# GitHub API JSON contains new lines (\n)

Tags: json, github, newline, github-api

I'm using the GitHub API to access the content of a certain file and I'm getting `\n` within the value of the JSON keys `content`. Why are those `\n` there?

The `content` is b64 encoded but obviously with those `\n` the decoding fails. I could write some code to remove the `\n` but what is the reason they are there?

Example: https://api.github.com/repos/grantae/mips32r1_xum/contents/README

```
{
  "name": "README",
  "path": "README",
  "sha": "2d77ad7f50cc6843ea06b0b48d6935c57b7b5577",
  "size": 3997,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/grantae/mips32r1_xum/contents/README?ref=master",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/grantae/mips32r1_xum/blob/master/README",
  "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/grantae/mips32r1_xum/git/blobs/2d77ad7f50cc6843ea06b0b48d6935c57b7b5577",
  "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grantae/mips32r1_xum/master/README",
  "type": "file",
  "content": "TUlQUzMyUjEgLSAxIEphbiAyMDE0DQotLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0N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\nZm9yIG1vcmUgaW5mb3JtYXRpb24uDQoNCg0KRW5qb3khDQoNCg==\n",
  "encoding": "base64",
  "_links": {
    "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/grantae/mips32r1_xum/contents/README?ref=master",
    "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/grantae/mips32r1_xum/git/blobs/2d77ad7f50cc6843ea06b0b48d6935c57b7b5577",
    "html": "https://github.com/grantae/mips32r1_xum/blob/master/README"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you tell that decoding fails? Using base64_decode() returns the correct result.

Comment: It doesn't. I tried here, which use base64_decode(), and it doesn't: https://www.functions-online.com/base64_decode.html

Comment: if you just want to get the raw data use [raw custom media type](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#custom-media-types) : `curl "https://api.github.com/repos/grantae/mips32r1_xum/contents/README" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw"`

Comment: That's actually correct and easier than how I'm doing it but... any reason why GitHub returns those `\n`?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use a different `base64` decoding library to deal with those `\n`

```
var base64 = require('js-base64').Base64;
var contents = base64.decode(res.content);
```

It would work the same as GitHub API call header:

```
'accept': 'application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw'
```

Comment: application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw response does not have sha,name,path ...
"name": "data.json",
    "path": "data.json",
    "sha": "78ef79086e8f95a26aa4d10cbca3777791ba9b70",
    "size": 14695,